# Add links to non-model items in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a few utility tools within my existing Django app, eg. a view which allows Django admin users to send an email to users, or generate embed codes for external websites, etc.

I want to add links to these tools to the Django admin index – what's the best way to go about this?

I know I can override the admin index template and (presumably) manually add a list of URLs, but this doesn't feel very "Django". The URLs for these utilities live in my app's `urls.py` – should I try extracting them out into their own app somehow?

I really just want to add a box like the one shown here, which links to three or four URLs – there must be a way!

[image: Django Admin example]

Comment: why not register it via `admin.py` file :\

Comment: @AliAref this is basically what I'm asking – how can I do this? This isn't an instance of `admin.modelAdmin`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just extending the admin index template to add my links – felt like overkill to create models/apps etc.